# Replace broken image icon with text

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, broken-image

I want to hide or remove the broken image icon whenever it pops up and replace that with text that reads: "Error with image." Right now, I have some jQuery that hides the broke image icon, but I cannot set and show the alt text this way. Do I need to have a replacement image or is there a way to show text whenever a broken image icon is hidden?

This is the jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("img").error(function () {
            $(this).hide();
        })
    .attr("src", "error with image");
    });
</script>
```

These are the fields in the table that are meant to show the image thumbnails:

```
<asp:ImageField HeaderText="Line dwg Thumb" DataImageUrlField="LineDrawThumbnail" NullDisplayText="error with image"  ControlStyle-Width="75px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
 </asp:ImageField>
 <asp:ImageField HeaderText="Profile Thumb" DataImageUrlField="ProfileThumbnail" NullDisplayText="error with image" ControlStyle-Width="75px"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
  </asp:ImageField>
```

Important side note: The database table that has the thumbnail images does not have any empty field for Profile Thumbnail or Line Draw Thumbnail--it just so happens that sometimes the thumbnail does not exist yet.

Comment: Why don't you add the property alt="error with image" to the images?

Comment: why can't you use alt?

Comment: If you know that sometimes a thumbnail won't exist, you should set a default image that says so.  Then, override that if the image is there.  You can't rely on any tag automatically displaying correctly on all browsers.

Comment: I've tried using alt text but the broke image icon still displays.

Comment: @SaraDeJaneiro why don't you fix the URLs? Seems like the only decent thing to do.

Comment: Fixing the URLs would take up a lot of time. We're talking a lot of images here. Plus, the images must be supplied by another person, and they have yet to send all the images needed it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is perfectly fine all you need to do is add text after you hide image

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("img").error(function () {
            $(this).hide();
        })
    .after('<p>error with image</p>');
    });
</script>
```